# Azure Web Application Firewall API

Tags: azure-waf

We have a problem with certain form inputs being blocked by the Azure WAF managed rules because one of our internal systems allows certain values and is not filtered by the WAF (different host.)

I'd like to use the WAF API (which I can't find documentation on) to do things like validate form input field values from our non-Azure-hosted application to check that when they are used on our Azure-hosted apps they will be accepted. Is this possible?

Simple (obvious) use case:

1. User enters new password outside Azure
2. Non-Azure app calls WAF API to validate password
3. Validated password can be safely entered into Azure-hosted app